# GWT server with get() and post() built on client end

Tags: javascript, ajax, gwt, client-server

This is more of a curiosity really, to see if some one has done anything similar, or if at all it is possible.

I'm working on a project that will get notification through external notifications. Now I could go about doing this by having notifications coming to my server and have a comet setup between my client and server.

BUT

I was wondering if I could write server logic into my client and listen out for notifications from external sources. Immediately one issue I see is, external sources would need callback URL etc, which I dont know if you could do from client side (unless one could use the IP address in that way).

As you can see it is more ideas and discussions if such a thing was possible, this is somewhat inspired by P2P models whereby you wouldn't be mediating things through your central server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT compiles (nearly) Java source into JavaScript, so compiled GWT apps can't do anything that traditional JavaScript running in the browser cannot do. The major advantage of bringing Java into the picture isn't automatic access to any/all JVM classes, but the ability to not only maintain Java sources, which tend to be easier to refactor and test as well as keep consistent with the server, and to compile that statically defined code into JavaScript, performing all kinds of optimizations at compile time that aren't possible for normal JavaScript.

So no, while you can have some code shared by the client (in a browser) and the server (running in a JVM), you can't run Tomcat/Jetty/etc in the browser just by using GWT to compile the java code into JS.

As you point out, even if this was possible, it would be difficult to get different clients to talk back and forth, without also requiring that the browsers can see and connect at will to one another. BitTorrent and Skype have different ways for facilitating this, and currently browsers do not allow anything like this - they are designed to make connections to other servers, not to allow connections to be made to them.

Push notifications from the web server to the browser are probably the best way forward, either through wrapping comet or the like, or through an existing GWT library like Atmosphere (see https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/samples/gwt-demo for a demo).

Comment: Thanks @Colin, I've decided to go with a comet architecture which will use a graceful WebSocket, so it can degrade if user using an old browser.